# Bring master to a particular commit back

Tags: git, git-merge

I created a `feature` branch from `master` and committed the changes. Before me merging into `master` someone else merged he/her branch  and it did not pass sonar quality check. Then, I too  merged my `feature` branch on `master` branch but upon merging I realised that sonar quality check is failing, this happened because `master` was already polluted even before my branch merge(I did not pay attention to build fail status before merging). So, now I want to set `master` to a commit(which I know) where the quality check was successful. But I can't directly make any push on `master` due to permissions, I need to raise pull request for it.

But before merging my `feature` branch into `master`, I did one more stupidity. I merged the changes from another branch which was failing at quality check. I didn't know what sonar quality checks are and thought since maven build was successful, X2 can also be merged but I made the matter worse.

```
            Another branch : X2 --- 
                                   \
Feature branch :  -- A -> B -> C -> X2 ->D -> E
                /                              \
Mater branch : A --->X1-------------------------- Merge commit ->
```

Now, I want master to be set at A again where all quality were passed. Please tell me what I can do here.
Just for information, the issues in sonar report are also from commits made before `A`. It appears Sonar is somehow considering old changes as new and applying checks on it.

Comment: All the quality checks should happen before merging onto master (better called "main"). When workin in a team, you should implement something like git-flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, going back is *kind* of easy, even considering that you have to keep current history:

```
git checkout the-revision-you-like
git reset --soft master
git commit -m "Let's go back to the-revision-you-like"
```

Now you have a revision on top of master that makes the project go back to the *contents* of the revision you like.

```
git checkout -b XXXX-revertToGoodSonar # create a new branch for this
git push origin @ # push the branch into remote
# now create the PR and merge
```

The tricky part now is the feature branches that were already merged but shouldn't have. For each one of them, you need to do this, so that git *thinks* that they haven't been merged ever (or they will give you headaches later on when you want to merge them again). Suppose one feature branch is made up of 5 straight revisions:

```
git checkout the-feature-branch~5 # checkout the exact revision where it was started from
git cherry-pick HEAD..the-feature-branch # reapply all revisions
git branch -f the-feature-branch # reset branch pointer to new revision
```

Now, the branch is *exactly* the same except for the fact that it is made up of revisions that git *thinks* that have never been merged. So when you want to merge them into the *fixed* master branch, it won't get confused about what should be merged.

Comment: Thanks for writing. I'm kind of new to git, therefore I've few doubts after reading your answer.  I did ```git reset --hard``` on my feature branch to a particular head which i  thought was causing the issue. The code was reset to earlier version but it still failed the quality check. Now, I wanted to ask does ```git reset --soft master``` will set it to very first commit of master from where I checked out?

Comment: `git reset --soft master` will just move the _pointer_ to which `HEAD` is pointing to to a different place. It won't modify any of the files. In this case, you are asking git to _think_ that it is pointing to the same revision where `master` is..... and then git will tell you (with `git status` or `diff --cached`) that you have maaaany many changes between the _new_ position where `HEAD` is and what you have in the working tree. At that point you wlll ask git to create a new revision right there (which will be following `master`). `master` won't move.

Comment: Okay, that is cleared. So that means, ```git checkout the-revision-you-like``` is to be done in ```master``` and not feature branch. Is this right?

Comment: Nope. `git checkout some-revision` will just get your working tree into a time machine and take it to that revision (back or forward in time). That revision should be a revision where code quality was working fine (before you started merging all those feature branches you shouldn't have in the first place).

Comment: actually, it's not just your working tree. It's the working tree and `HEAD` pointer. in other words, you _go_ to that revision.

Comment: okay. That's a very nice feature, i wasn't aware of.

Comment: So now, I've create a good-Sonar branch from the revision which I wanted(before the inclusion of faulty merge). Could you please also confirm ```# now create the PR and merge``` means PR for good-Sonar (updated till C commit)--> Feature branch which contains faulty merges too?

Comment: Sorry to ask these naive questions but I'm don't want to mess anymore and want things to be perfect in master anyhow.

Comment: If you created a branch called good-sonar on that revision and you are on it, then run `git reset --soft master; git commit -m "Going back in time to correct code quality"`. at that moment, good-sonar should have a single revision after master that basically takes back everything that was committed after the revision that you want master to go back to. Push that branch, Create the MR, merge into master. Now master has been _corrected_ by getting its content just the way it was back in time before merging those funky branches (though they are still in its history).

Comment: ... and I understand that you want to move forward fast... but if you are not careful and understand what's going on, you are bound to shoot yourself in the foot faster than you think.

Comment: Yeah, I learnt that hard way. However, your answer helped me learn new commands and solve the issue.